# fullcalendar showing wrong date

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This is my event array :

```
[Object { title="Event1",  start="2016-09-14"}, Object { title="Event2",  start="2016-09-06"}]
```

Event 1 is showing on 2016-09-12 and event 2 is showing on 2016-09-05

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    viewRender: function (view, element) {
        var add_url = '<a class="add-task" href="#" title="Assign Applicant"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>';
        $(".fc-day-number").after(add_url);
    },
    editable: true,
    events: getEvent,
    dayClick: function () {
        //   alert('a day has been clicked!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the issue. The error is in `viewRender` function. After removing it dates are shown as expected.

First of all, this is wrong (the error is specifically in this line):

```
$(".fc-day-number").after(add_url);
```

because you need to refer to specific event.

Second, [viewRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/) is not the right function to use because it's intended for rendering whole view.

For adding custom buttons you can use [eventAfterRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/) for example:

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
    var add_url = '<a class="add-task" href="#" title="Assign Applicant"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></a>';
    element.after(add_url);
},
```

Also check [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/), maybe it's better to use that instead.